# How can I move store switcher from footer to top header bar in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, layout, frontend

I want to move my store switcher from footer to top header bar like this

like show this is footer screen shoot
[image]

[image]

at here right side of create account link in Magento 2.4

Answer (score 0):

to move store switcher to top header so should out code in default.xml file

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header.panel" after="header.links" />
```

here my default.xml file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
        <move element="store_switcher" destination="header.panel" after="header.links" />
        <referenceBlock name="custom-header-link" remove="true" />  
    </body>
</page>
```

from using this i successfully move the store switcher from footer to top header see the below screen shoot.

[image]

[image]